# Xamarin Forms ListView scroll position

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a very simple master-detail view with the list of the meetings on the left and the selected meeting details on the main area.

There are some meetings which details screen is bigger and it is scrollable.

The problem I have is:

- go to one of the bigger meetings (like meeting #11)
- scroll down a little bit
- go to the the meeting which screen fits perfectly without scrolling (meeting #2 for instance)
- the meeting details is cut at the top (see below)

**After scrolling down meeting #11**

[image: After scrolling down meeting #11]

**After selecting meeting #2**

[image: After selecting meeting #2]

All I do is just change the binding context of the details screen.

Is this some kind of bug / feature or what?
I could try to add some piece of code that scrolls to the top after the selected item has been changed but I would like to avoid this, especially that my ListView contains a header and there is only API to scroll to the first item element.

Xamarin Studio 6.1.2 (build 44)

Xamarin Forms 2.3.2.127

**Update 1 - added page XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewScrollToTop"
    x:Class="ListViewScrollToTop.ListViewScrollToTopPage">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
        <ListView x:Name="MeetingsView" WidthRequest="300" VerticalOptions="Fill"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            BackgroundColor="Teal"
            ItemTapped="OnMeetingTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Location}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="MeetingDetailsView"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            Header="{Binding .}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Location}"/>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10" Padding="12" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <local:RepeaterView Spacing="1"
                                    ItemsSource = "{Binding Documents}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Olive" Margin="12"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                                </local:RepeaterView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Update 2 - added Android test feedback**

I cannot reproduce this bug on Android, only iOS.

**Update 3 - test without the header**

Even if I remove the details header, I can observe the issue.

**Update 4 - linked solution demonstrating the problem**

[ListViewScrollToTop](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6nz5k5a82mtji8/ListViewScrollToTop.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Looks like you problem is Detail's page title - could it be you setting it up when selecting meeting? Check your detail page.

Comment: I don't think so. There is no problem if I go to the meeting #2 page directly. And there is nothing in the code that deals with scrolling - everything regarding this is out of the box. Anyway I have updated the question and I have added the page xaml.

Comment: I recall that there was similar issue discussed on Xamarin forum, but could not find it quick. Can I suggest to place listviews inside Vertical Stacklayouts... or use a Grid Instaed your main StackLayout.

Comment: might this disscussuin will help you https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19874/listview-inside-stacklayout-a-height-problem

Comment: @DanyDaKur: it behaves the same with Grid instead of StackLayout

Comment: I will check the provided link, thank you.